# Fixed-point of a monotonically increasing function on an ordered set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to show the following:

Let $ S $ be a nonempty ordered set such that every subset $ E \subset S $ has both a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. Suppose that $ f: S \rightarrow S $ is a monotonically increasing function. Show that there exists some $ x \in S $ such that $ f(x) = x $.

However, I believe the statement is false. If we let $ S = [0,1] $ and $ f(x) = x+1 $, then clearly no such $ x \in S $ exist.

Comment: Your counterexample is not a function $[0,1]\to [0,1]$. The important fact is that the function maps $S$ to itself. For $S=[0,1]$ you can actually picture this : the graph of $f$ in the square $[0,1]^2$ will cross $y=x$ if $f$ is increasing

Comment: @Sora Ahhh what a blunder, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E=\{s\in S \vert s\leq f(s)\}$. The the greatest lower bound of $S$ is in $E$ so it is non-empty. Let $x$ be the least upper bound of $E$. Let us show that $f(x)=x$.

First, for any $s\in E$, $s\leq x$ so $s\leq f(s)\leq f(x)$ (the first inequality is the definition of $E$, the second the fact that $f$ is increasing) thus $f(x)$ is also an upper bound of $E$, hence $x\leq f(x)$ as we chose the least upper bound.

On the other hand, since $x\leq f(x)$ and $f$ is increasing, we get $f(x)\leq f(f(x))$. In particular, this means $f(x)\in E$ thus $f(x)\leq x$.

Hence $x=f(x)$.